# How to get 'proxied' object from an existing dynamic proxy

Tags: java, algorithm, design-patterns, reflection, aop

Is there an some API like `Proxy.getProxiedObject()`, that will return the original object of a dynamic proxy? I would like, for example, to invoke equals on the proxied objects, rather than on the dynamic proxies themselves, like in the following example:

```
public class ProxyTest implements InvocationHandler {

    public static Object createProxy(Object target) {
        Class<? extends Object> clazz = target.getClass();
        return Proxy.newProxyInstance(clazz.getClassLoader(), clazz.getInterfaces(), new ProxyTest());      
    }

    public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args) throws Exception {
        // PROXIED OBJECTS COMPARISON - DESIRED
//      return Proxy.getProxiedObject(proxy).equals(Proxy.getProxiedObject(args[0]));

        // DYNAMIC PROXIES COMPARISON - UNDESIRED
//      return proxy.equals(args[0]);

        return null;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Object proxied = createProxy(new Object());
        System.out.println(proxied.equals(proxied));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's any API available for this; but I built a workaround this using the API that retrieves the `InvocationHandler` from any `Proxy` object, and the one that tests where or not a `Class` is a `Proxy` class:

> - [`InvocationHandler getInvocationHandler(Object proxy) throws IllegalArgumentException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html#getInvocationHandler(java.lang.Object))
> - [`boolean isProxyClass(Class<?> cl)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html#isProxyClass(java.lang.Class))

Using these I created an abstract extension of `InvocationHandler` to keep a reference to the object being **proxied**, with a static utility to retrieve the **proxied** object out of any *potential* `Proxy` object, and a factory utility for creating `Proxy`s using the target object:

```
    public abstract class ProxiedSavedInvocationHandler implements InvocationHandler {
        public static Object getProxied(Object proxy) {
            if (!Proxy.isProxyClass(proxy.getClass())) 
                return null;

            InvocationHandler handler = Proxy.getInvocationHandler(proxy);
            return (handler instanceof ProxiedSavedInvocationHandler) ? 
                    ((ProxiedSavedInvocationHandler)handler).proxied : null;
        }

        protected final Object proxied;

        public ProxiedSavedInvocationHandler(Object proxied) { 
            this.proxied = proxied; 
        }

        public Object getProxied() {
            return proxied;
        }

        public Object createProxy() {
            Class<? extends Object> clazz = proxied.getClass();
            return Proxy.newProxyInstance(clazz.getClassLoader(), clazz.getInterfaces(), this);
        }
    }
```

Then I just used the newly created class like this:

```
        class MyProxiedSavedInvocationHandler extends ProxiedSavedInvocationHandler {
        ...
        }

        ProxiedSavedInvocationHandler handler = new MyProxiedSavedInvocationHandler(target); 
        Object proxy = handler.createProxy();

        // DESIRED API THROUGH STATIC UTILIY
        Object proxied1 = ProxiedSavedInvocationHandler.getProxied(proxy);

        // DESIRED API THROUGH INSTANCE UTILIY
        Object proxied2 = handler.getProxied();
```

The only dependency on this solution is having the `ProxiedSavedInvocationHandler` utility class where all the logic and new APIs are located. This class can be extended even to include APIs to delegate behavior to other `InvocationHandler`s transparently; but the minimum required is there.

The following is a full working example application of this solution:

```
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationHandler;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.lang.reflect.Proxy;

public class ProxyTest {

    static class MyProxiedSavedInvocationHandler extends ProxiedSavedInvocationHandler {
        public MyProxiedSavedInvocationHandler(Object proxied) {
            super(proxied);
        }

        public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args) throws Exception {
            if (!method.getName().equals("equals"))
                return method.invoke(proxied, args);

            Object other = ProxiedSavedInvocationHandler.getProxied(args[0]);
            System.out.println("====");
            System.out.println("\tRunning 'equals' inside proxy with:");
            System.out.println("\tthis: " + proxied);
            System.out.println("\tother: " + other);
            System.out.println("====");
            return proxied.equals(other);
        }
    }

    static abstract class ProxiedSavedInvocationHandler implements InvocationHandler {
        public static Object getProxied(Object proxy) {
            if (!Proxy.isProxyClass(proxy.getClass())) 
                return null;

            InvocationHandler handler = Proxy.getInvocationHandler(proxy);
            return (handler instanceof ProxiedSavedInvocationHandler) ? 
                    ((ProxiedSavedInvocationHandler)handler).proxied : null;
        }

        protected final Object proxied;

        public ProxiedSavedInvocationHandler(Object proxied) { 
            this.proxied = proxied; 
        }

        public Object getProxied() {
            return proxied;
        }

        public Object createProxy() {
            Class<? extends Object> clazz = proxied.getClass();
            return Proxy.newProxyInstance(clazz.getClassLoader(), clazz.getInterfaces(), this);
        }
    }

    // TO TEST EDGE SCENARIONS
    private static Object createProxy(Class<? extends Object> clazz, InvocationHandler handler) {
        return Proxy.newProxyInstance(clazz.getClassLoader(), clazz.getInterfaces(), handler);
    }

    // MAIN
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // EDGE SCENARIOS
        Object proxiedFromNotEnhancedProxy = 
                ProxiedSavedInvocationHandler.getProxied(createProxy(Object.class, (p, m, a) -> null));
        Object proxiedFromNotAProxy = 
                ProxiedSavedInvocationHandler.getProxied(new Object());
        System.out.println("proxied from NOT ENHANCED PROXY: " + proxiedFromNotEnhancedProxy);
        System.out.println("proxied from NOT A PROXY: " + proxiedFromNotAProxy);
        System.out.println();

        // FUNCTIONALITY DESIRED
        Object target = new Object();
        ProxiedSavedInvocationHandler handler = new MyProxiedSavedInvocationHandler(target); 

        Object proxy = handler.createProxy();
        Object proxied1 = ProxiedSavedInvocationHandler.getProxied(proxy);
        Object proxied2 = handler.getProxied();

        System.out.println("target: " + target);
        System.out.println("proxied1: " + proxied1);
        System.out.println("target == proxied1: " + (target == proxied1));
        System.out.println("proxy.equals(proxy): " + proxy.equals(proxy));
    }
}
```

[Complete code on GitHub](https://github.com/marco-ruiz/stackoverflow-qa/tree/master/so-common/src/main/java/so/a56175511)